# Cant add local image as background image in HTML/CSS

Tags: css, url, styles, background-image, filepath

I am a beginner to CSS, and I am stuck on this issue since yesterday.

I have tried all the solutions suggested in Stack Overflow, but nothing seems to work. I tried adding a local image using both internal and external CSS.

The code:

```
body {
     background-size: cover;
     background-image: URL('Penguins.jpg');
}
```

- The image, CSS file and HTML file are in the same folder.
- The image displays fine when inserted using `<img>` tag
- Background image shows  when using an image from the Internet, i.e.: `https://images.pexels.com/photos/210019/pexels-photo-210019.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=action-asphalt-auto-210019.jpg&fm=jpg`.

The most frustrating thing is the code works fine in my Windows 7 PC, but not on my Windows 10 PC.

Comment: Have you tried a "./" in front of the image path? So it would be "./Penguins.jpg".

Comment: Is the image filename exactly `Penguins.jpg`? Or is the capitalization different?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can see this not working is perhaps you don't have the image where it should be. If the image is not within the same project folder as your code then you may need to use a directory path to get to it.

For example, if your CSS/index/JavaScript files are in a folder, and the image is in your documents folder on your desktop, you would need to do something along the lines of .../desktop/Penguins.jpg. Otherwise, try moving the image file into the same folder as your website project files.